# Can an element have variable oxidation states in a compound?

Tags: oxidation-state, electronegativity

Take propanoic acid for example. If I assign oxidation states to the 3 carbons in it using the idea that the more electronegative element gets all the electrons in the bonds it makes, the 3 carbons get -3( the one in the CH3), -2( the one in the middle), and +3( the one in the acid group).

Is this conclusion correct? The reason I doubt is that all the examples we've ever been given in class, we've assumed all the atoms of the same element to have the same oxidation state.

Comment: Yes, the same element can occur in a compound in different oxidation states. Consider sulfur in thiosulfate  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thiosulfate  Your teachers have just been keeping it simple so that your classmates understand the basic principle.

Comment: @Waylander, thanks. Are my numbers of propanoic acid correct though?

Comment: Oxidation numbers are not a very useful concept when it comes to organic compounds but yes, your numbers are correct